# ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting() deprecated in ICS; how to use getActiveNetworkInfo() instead

Tags: android, synchronization, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

According to the Android SDK docs for `ConnectivityManager`, `getBackgroundDataSetting()` is deprecated in Android 4.x, and `getActiveNetworkInfo()` should be used instead to see if background data is disabled:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting()

But, with Sync turned off, when I query the `NetworkInfo` object within my Service, there's nothing that implies background data is disabled:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
// getBackgroundDataSetting always returns true on Android 4.x
if (connMgr != null && !connMgr.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
    Log.i(WootsUp.TAG, "background data off");
    return;
}

if (connMgr != null) {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null || netInfo.isAvailable() == false || netInfo.isConnected() == false) {
        Log.i(WootsUp.TAG, "no active network");
        return;
    }
}
```

Neither `isAvailable()` nor `isConnect()` return false when I have Sync turned off.

Is there a different method in `NetworkInfo` I should be querying instead to see if background data is disabled?  FYI I'm using an alarm-driven Service, and not using the SyncAdapter APIs, if that makes a difference.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The 'background data' setting has moved in ICS. It is separate from the 'Sync' setting.

You can find the 'background data' setting under Settings -> Data Usage -> Menu button -> Restrict Background Data.

getActiveNetworkInfo() does respect this setting.

See also https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17456

Comment: Your answer is completely unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: @JuanAcevedo I don't agree.

Rob seemed to be under the assumption that background data should be disabled as soon as sync was disabled (*with Sync turned off, when I query the NetworkInfo object within my Service, there's nothing that implies background data is disabled*). I think that's why he saw unexpected behaviour.

From ICS and onwards, sync and background data are separate settings. It is possible to have sync disabled and background data enabled, and vice versa.

So in my opinion this is definitely related.